# In C# how to open third form inside first form when i click a button of the second form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

In my `Windows Forms` application, I have 3 different `Form`s (*Form1, Form2, Form3*)

- **Form1** Contains a Button and a Panel (button1, panel1)

  [image: Form1 Image]
- **Form2** Contains only a button (button)

  [image: Form2 Image]
- **Form3** Contains nothing

  [image: Form3 Image]

In Form1 when I click button1 , Form2 opens in panel1

[image: (see in image)]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.TopLevel = false;
    panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
    f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    f2.Show();
}
```

**Now, inside Form2, when i click the button, I want the Form3 open inside Form1's panel, I've tried this code...**

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f1.panel1.Controls.Clear();
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.TopLevel = false;
    f1.panel1.Controls.Add(f3);
    f3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    f3.Show();
}
```

***Note: In Form1 I've changed the modifier to public for the Panel***

Comment: And what is the problem? Is it not working? Is it crashing? It's quite unclear from only what you wrote.

Comment: "I've tried this code..." and...what? You didn't mention the problem. (Tip: "It's not working" is not the answer we're looking for here... a bit more debugging work would help)

Comment: P.S. this business of adding the form's controls to another panel is a bit odd...why not just open and close the forms like normal?

Comment: This: `f1.panel1.Controls.Clear();` and this: `panel1.Controls.Clear();` combined are going to be the end of your application. Read about UserControls. Replace the Forms with some of these custom objects.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...  My code is not working..  I've tried many times..

Comment: The proper way is by raising events.  The child forms shouldn't know about each other.  The parent form should be listening to a child form's event that you create, something like `ShowOtherForm(object sender, EventArgs e)`  When this gets raised, the parent form does the work to show the other form.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Create functions in Form1 to Show the other Forms:**

```
class Form1
{
    public void ShowForm2() {...}
    public void ShowForm3() {...}
    // TODO: think about: do you need IsForm2Shown?
    // TODO: think about what you want if ShowForm2 is called twice
    ...
```

}

**Step 2: Let Form2 know about Form1. Give Form2 a function to show Form3 inside Form1**

```
class Form2
{
    public Form1 Form1 {get; set;}

    protected void ShowForm3InsideForm1()
    {
        this.Form1.ShowForm3();
    }
}
```

Whenever Form one creates Form2 it should fill property `Form1`. So inside `Form1.ShowForm2()`:

```
var form2 = new Form2()
{
   Form1 = this,
   ...
}
form2.Show();
```

**Step 3: whenever you find in Form 2 that you want to "show form 3 in form 1", just call the proper function**

```
// Somewhere inside Form2 code you decide that you want to show Form3 inside Form1:
this.ShowForm3InsideForm1();
```

Simple comme bonjour!